# How to resolve (com.apple.ShazamKit error 202.) when using ShazamKit

Tags: ios, swift

I've been trying to add Shazam matching to my app using the new `ShazamKit`. I've used Apple's sample code found [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/shazamkit/building_a_custom_catalog_and_matching_audio) and adapted it slightly.

```swift
import ShazamKit
import AVFAudio
import Combine

@available(iOS 15.0, *)
class ShazamMatcher: NSObject, ObservableObject, SHSessionDelegate {

    // MARK: - Properties

    @Published var result: SHMatch?
    @Published var isRecording = false

    private var isInitialSetupDone = false
    private var session: SHSession?
    private let audioEngine = AVAudioEngine()

    // MARK: - Actions

    func match() throws {
        result = nil

        session = SHSession()
        session?.delegate = self

        try doInitialSetupIfNeeded()

        AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().requestRecordPermission { [weak self] success in
            guard success, let self = self else {
                return
            }
            try? self.audioEngine.start()
            self.isRecording = true
        }
    }

    func stopMatching() {
        audioEngine.stop()
        isRecording = false
    }

    // MARK: - Setup

    private func doInitialSetupIfNeeded() throws {
        guard !isInitialSetupDone else {
            return
        }

        let audioFormat = AVAudioFormat(
            standardFormatWithSampleRate: audioEngine.inputNode.outputFormat(forBus: 0).sampleRate,
            channels: 1
        )
        audioEngine.inputNode.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize: 2048, format: audioFormat) { [weak session] buffer, audioTime in
            session?.matchStreamingBuffer(buffer, at: audioTime)
        }

        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.record)
        isInitialSetupDone = true
    }

    // MARK: - SHSessionDelegate

    func session(_ session: SHSession, didFind match: SHMatch) {
        // Handle match here
    }

    func session(_ session: SHSession, didNotFindMatchFor signature: SHSignature, error: Error?) {
        // Handle error here
    }

}
```

However, when calling `match()`, the delegate eventually reports an error `The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.ShazamKit error 202.)`

I've added a new key using my bundle identifier for the ShazamKit services and downloaded the `.p8` file. Do I need this file and if so, how?

Has anybody been able to resolve this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a solution. First, apparently the inter-app audio entitlement has to be enabled.

Second, it seems like you need a `SHSignatureGenerator` as well (I though it would be enough to call `matchStreamingBuffer`

Here's code that works:
https://github.com/heysaik/ShazamKit-Demo/blob/main/Shazam/ViewController.swift

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to your developer account (developer.apple.com).
2. Under "identifiers" choose the bundleid you're working on.
3. Choose the tab "App Services".
4. Check the checkbox "ShazamKit" and save.

[image]